# Stetho-Timber library issue with new Timber version 4.1.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, stetho, timber-android

While I was trying to use stetho-timber Library in my Android application I faced this problem:

> Error:Module 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-timber:1.3.1' depends on one
>   or more Android Libraries but is a jar

What's wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting in its codes I found that it uses timber v3.0.1!

Just add this to your build.gradle dependencies tag to exclude timber within the stetho library,
cause it is an old version and conflicts with new one:

```
dependencies {  
    compile ("com.facebook.stetho:stetho-timber:1.3.1") {  
        exclude group: "com.jakewharton.timber", module: "timber"  
    }  
    .  
    .  
    .
```

I have recently found Facebook Stetho Library and using it is fantastic, give it a try! :)